# wpf - is it a harmfull to call database from the xaml code-behind?

Tags: wpf, multithreading, xaml, service

I am supposed to work on a wpf legacy application( and desktop app is a new beast for me).
 I have read that consumming task should not be launched on the ui thread : but I find this following code in the code behind of a view :

```
bool isSearching = true;
try 
{
    Task<ProductSearchResult>.Factory                           
    .StartNew(() => DBCatalogService.Search( search.Criteria, search.CriteriaPage, search.CriteriaResultByPage)    
    .ContinueWith(res => LoadResult(res, search.Criteria, search.CriteriaPage, search.CriteriaResultByPage), 
            TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext())                          
    .ContinueWith(s => isSearching = false);
}
catch
{
...
}
```

I am wondering it will not cause any trouble.
I know that it's sounds weird to call the database directly from the view code behind, but I just want to know if it could freeze the ui thread or something like this.
Thank you for your advice on this matter.

Comment: Which .net framework are you targeting at? Because you could consider using async await instead of traditional tasks with continuations.

Comment: The application is targeting framework 4.5.1. Does using async await here would make a difference ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is : does the sample code that I provided would block the UI thread and have to be considered harmfull or not ?

The call to the `DBCatalogService.Search` method will *not* block the UI thread since it is being invoked on a background thread using the task parallel library (TPL).

The call to the `LoadResult` method will however be executed on the UI thread once the task that calls the Search method has completed.

This is fine though since this method probably sets some properties of some UI elements based on the result of the search and you must do this on the UI thread. This is because WPF controls have thread affinity, meaning that a control can only be accessed on the thread on which it was originally created.

So no, the sample code you have provided should not be considered "harmfull" in terms of UI responsiveness assuming that the `LoadResult` doesn't perform any strange and potentially long-running operations.

Answer (score 0):

If you block the UI thread (dispatcher thread) with a long-running operation such as a synchronous DB request, your application will be unresponsive until the thread is unblocked.

You can avoid this by either:

- Doing the blocking/synchronous operation on another thread
- Making the operation non-blocking/asynchronous
- Both of the above

Using async/await can make your code read much like the synchronous form, but with asynchronous behaviour. It should be much clearer than the code sample you give in the question. However you need an async form of your search.

If you do use another thread, remember to dispatch back onto the UI thread if you have to update UI properties.

Comment: Hello, as I told before I am aware of that : this is effectively what I have read on the web. My question is : does the sample code that I provided would block the UI thread and have to be considered harmfull or not ?   Anyway thank you for your help.